# Conexão JAVA com BANCO

Tags: java, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Não estou conseguindo conectar o java com banco, pois aparece um erro como na imagem,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: O servidor de banco está ativo? coloque o código fonte como texto e não como imagem assim outras pessoas tbm podem ajudar.

Comment: Coloque o código não um print dele, assim ficará mais fácil de testar.

Comment: Você configurou seu MySQL para utilizar a porta 3307? Pergunto, pois, a porta padrão é a 3306.
E quanto ao driver... Dê preferência para "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver". O driver que você está usando, apesar de compatível, era utilizado antes do projeto (o driver, no caso) ser doado para o MySQL.

Comment: Sim!, o normal é 3306, estava testando 3307 e nehuma funciona, adicionei o drive do propio Netbeans o drive carrega normal , a conexão que não é feita, já instalei o xampp  novante e continua a msm coisa!

Comment: Poste o código, assim você abrange quem usa leitor de tela.

Answer (score 3):

Somente [wrapped exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/chained.html) retornada não ajuda, o ideal seria termos todo o stack trace e obter a **root cause**.

Porem vou indicar algumas possibilidades, que podem ajudar a quem obter uma *Communications Link Failure*:

Inicialmente encontre o arquivo de configurações do MySQL:

> Linux   = /etc/mysql/my.cnf
>
> Windows = C:\MinhaLocalizacaoDoRDBMS\mysql\bin\my.ini

**- Porta correta?**

A **3306** é a porta padrão do MySQL, você está usando a **3307**.

Um [netstat](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) pode ajudar na investigação:

> - win = C:>netstat -an | findstr 3306
> - linux = $ netstat -ln | grep 3306

**- Loopback interface está ok?**

Tente alterar o localhost para **127.0.0.1**, caso funcione vale a pena dar uma olhada como seu SO está resolvendo o [loopback](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback).

> linux = /etc/hosts
>
> windows = C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file

- **Configuração de binding**

Problemas de [binding](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address) são comuns, tente explicitar a configuração na guia [mysqld] o default seria 0.0.0.0 e aceitaria todos os hosts ipv4:

```
bind-address    = 127.0.0.1
```

ou explicite para todas as interfaces

```
bind-address    = 0.0.0.0
```

**- Mantenha *"Skip Networking"* comentado**

```
# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
#skip-networking
```